# tqdm df.progress_apply() functions calculates wrong number of total iterations

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I am using the tqdm pandas progress_apply function which shows a progress bar. It is showing a total number of iterations equal to the max number of columns in the dataframe (14 in my case) instead of rows 43.

```
df.shape
Out[131]:  (43, 14)
```

If I run:

```
tqdm.pandas(desc="Processing:")
df.progress_apply(extract_loc, axis =1)
```

It assumes I have 14 iterations to go instead of 43:

[Snapshot of above run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZCwN.jpg)

I tried passing total manually but get following error:

```
tqdm.pandas(desc="Processing:", total = len(df))
df.progress_apply(extract_loc, axis =1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaswani/anaconda/envs/water/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-133-7da38f5c504e>", line 1, in <module>
    df.progress_apply(extract_loc, axis =1)
  File "/Users/kaswani/anaconda/envs/water/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 513, in inner
    t = tclass(*targs, total=total, **tkwargs)
```

> TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument
>   'total'

Using the old format of code which is deprecated works:

```
tqdm_pandas(tqdm(desc="Processing:", total = len(df)))
df.progress_apply(extract_loc, axis =1)
```

[Running with the deprecated code works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD3JN.jpg)

Has anyone encountered something similar? Thanks for the help in advance. If I can pass the total value to the code manually that should fix it.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/322 and from there https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/pull/299

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered a similar bug with wrong `progress_map` approximation on pandas 2.1.3.
For anyone wondering this (based on OP's code) fixed it:

```
# My df has nan values in multiple columns, they won't be processed
total = df.notna().sum().sum()

tqdm.pandas(desc="Processing", total=total)
result = df.progress_map(my_function, na_action='ignore')
```